# My project shows errors unexpectedly. Is there a good method that can be used to plan a project before starting and deploying it?

Tags: project-management, error-handling, project-structure, project-planning

I have completed a project. But errors unexpectedly occurs anytime when the user inputs data in it. Yesterday my program was performing very well.
But today when the client tested the project it had some unexpected errors.
Is it a normal thing to have such unexpected errors?
Or Is there a way or a technique to verify that the program has no error.

Comment: "But today when the client tested the project it had some unexpected errors. Is it a normal thing to have such unexpected errors?"  As normal as it gets, unfortunately.

Comment: I recommend you go through your code and post a question **with code** in stackoverflow if needed. But as this question is written is pretty much useless.

Comment: Start here https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ Also note, debugging help is 100% off-topic on this site.

Comment: Cauchy, i can debug those errors.But the issue is that i can't debug them while they are hidden. However i understood what you mean.

Comment: @Neil You should consider changing your statement to: "As normal as it gets when proper QA processes are not in use."

Comment: @PeterAbolins Because errors in production never happen otherwise?  Have you been programming for very long?  Ideally you reduce as much as possible errors, but you can never completely eliminate them, not for lack of trying.  It's smarter to have a contingency plan for *when* things go wrong and not if.

Comment: @Neil The point was "...unexpected errors any time the user provides an input...". That could definitely be mitigated with proper QA. And no, I haven't been programming for very long. I wrote my first program in 1984, and started programming professionally in 1995, so I guess I am still a beginner...

Comment: @PeterAbolins No need for the sarcasm.  A simple "yes" would have sufficed.  I was just trying to understand if you meant to say that errors in production *can* be avoided entirely or you were implying something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Unexpected errors" is a behavior which we software developers do not like. We have to prepare for that:

- Add a logging mechanism to your application to find out when those errors happened and what users did to "provoke" them.
- During development, write many automated tests. Those tests include the "happy path" where everything is simple, some tests with edge cases, and some tests with "invalid input".
- When you detected a way to provoke such an error, write a test for it, then write the code for fixing that bug. Such you create a safety net preventing you from re-creating the error during a later bugfix.
- There is no practical way to prove that a program is completely correct. But at least the test suite proves, that it copes well with many cases.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2223/are-useful-answers-to-off-topic-questions-useful-to-the-community